# Дружественные URL выдают 404

Tags: .htaccess, modx

Столкнулся с проблемой, настройки дружественных урлов для сайта. Сначала алиасы не применялись в принципе, сейчас же алиасы работают, только отдают 404.

.htaccess вроде бы сконфигурировал, AllowOverride All добавил.

Дружественные урл включил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В .htaccess лучше самому не лезть, а просто переименовать тот что идет в комплекте - тогда проблем не будет. 404 какраз получается только изза проблем с ним - когда он не переименован, или когда сервер вообще не поддерживает htaccess(для связки php-fpm+nginx дружественные урлы настраиваются по-другому).

Comment: Самое смешное было в том, что действительно забыл раскомментировать htaccess, так все было настроено правильно :)